# visual studio color theme problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, themes, color-scheme

I am using a version of [Vim's wombat color theme for Visual studio 2008](http://mohundro.com/blog/2008/01/11/my-attempt-at-converting-the-vim-wombat-theme-to-support-visual-studio/). Whenever I open a window of a plugin (Visual AssistX in my case), the theme colors change. Especially the "User keywords" category - class names and methods. For some reason it changes to dark blue. Since its a dark background theme the dark blue text is almost impossible to read.

If I close visual studio and re-open it, the theme renders fine. And the problem happens when I open a plugin window.

The above problem is not just with this theme, it's with any theme I have tried so far :(

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to rectify it?

Comment: You should probably move your answer to an actual answer post.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem. The plugin (Visual AssistX) had its own fonts and colors settings which was overriding VS fonts and color settings. Changing them fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I disabled the Database in C/C++ while having enabled only the Visual Assist intellisense.

So make sure you `Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable Database` is `FALSE` and `Rescan Solution Interval` is not `0` (default is `300`).